# How to restore Dock Icon Badges after killall Dock?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, dock, notifications

I need to run `killall Dock` in a script I use regularly, in order for it to work.

Unfortunately all the badges in the Dock disappears when Dock is killed, and don't reappear until they're modified individually by the the application in question. So if the Mail application for example has 123 unread emails as the badge, the badge disappears until I read an email or receive a new one.

How can I restore the badges for all apps at the same time though, in my script?

Comment: Having the same issue. Would love to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

In order to restore the badges, you need to add this command to your shell script:

```
defaults write com.apple.systempreferences AttentionPrefBundleIDs 1
```

...and then tell your script to kill Dock, so the next Dock instance is loaded with the new setting:

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I just tried this and it didn't work, the badges were missing when the dock restarted :weep: